# Cannot connect to attached SQL database

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, authentication

I'm using linq to sql with Microsoft SQL **Server Database File** (SqlClient) as a data source.
**The db file** was created by Visual Studio 2010 while adding the connection (Database Explorer -> Add Connection).
Using this method I was unable to create a db with SQL auth, so I'm using Windows Authentication.

EDIT: Note that it's not a connection to a database, it's a connection to a database file.

1) Is it possible to create a database file with sql authentication? (I assume it is the root of the problem).

2) Connection works fine on my computer under different acocunts. However, running the release on other machine results in an exception being thrown.

Exception details:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26
>   - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I've tried to set the db path manually, but I guess it's not the issue.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT2: the connection string I'm using:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\OperatorResults.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=10;User Instance=True"
```

Comment: AFAIK SqlClient doesn't access SQL Server Files directly! so yes you a running SQL Server etc.

Comment: I was hoping to achieve results similar to using sqllite database. 
The SQL server I have is what was installed together with visual studio.

Comment: that's is not possible - SQLLite is a "standalone DB" - the client accesses the file - but SQL Server is really different, as the name says it is a SERVER database and needs to be accessed through the server process... what's wrong with the SQLLite solution you have ?

Comment: No integrated LINQ to SQL support. I know there are some drivers available, but I'm trying to avoid incorporating them into my application.
I have found some application I've done a long time ago and I didn't have such problems.

If I'm able to connect to the database file from my machine using Windows Auth, what could be wrong on another computer? I'm pretty sure the paths are ok. The context present the right connection string.

Comment: btw: please don't add C#, ... into the title. We have tags for this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, how was SQL Server installed? With Windows Authentication only or Mixed Mode authentication. If it was just Windows Authentication that explains why you were unable to use SQL Server authentication. If mixed mode authentication is enabled then you need an account that has sysadmin or CREATE DATABASE privileges.

As for your second question, did you modify connection string to match the connection configuration of another machine? If not, try doing that. From the exception above it seems that your connection string is connecting to a wrong server or the server instance is not running.

Comment: I don't have a MS SQL server installed, i want it to be something like sqllite.

Comment: If you have standalone file that can be attached to SQL Server express then you need SQL Server express on the release computer. Could you edit your question and post your connection string please?

Comment: Is SQL Express installed on the release computer or is it running a fully featured SQL Server installation? Your connection string works with a file which is attached to a running instance of SQL Server Express, but this will not work if SQL Server other than Express version is installed. In that case you need to attach OperatorResults.mdf to the SQL Server.

Comment: In addition to my previous comment. Have a look at these two links on MSDN that deal with connecting to SQL Server (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247257.aspx) and this one that shows how to use SQL Server Compact Edition (comes with Visual Studio 2010 SP1) (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg606540.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You want [Microsoft SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx)

It allows a file based connection.

Comment: That is exactly what I am using.

Comment: @grrawr One thing to check if express is installed on your target machine. I believe it is a different connection provider. Just a thought.